# How to select the first record from multiple records from SOSL query

Tags: apex, limits, sosl

I am using SOSL query:

`List<List<Account>> acclist = [FIND :newstring IN ALL FIELDS RETURNING Account(id,Name,FirstName,LastName,Territory_vod__c,NPI_vod__c where RecordType.Name='Prescriber' ) ];`

`newString` is set and consists of names.
So,if there are 3 account with name `test` then it will retrieve all those accounts.

I want to retrieve only one account record for each value in `newString`.

Is it possible to retrieve only the first record for each name that is matching with account name in SOSL query itself(by using something like LIMIT).**I need it in SOSL query itself**.

Comment: you could use `Limit`. Something like `List<List<Account>> acclist = [FIND :newstring IN ALL FIELDS RETURNING Account(id,Name,FirstName,LastName,Territory_vod__c,NPI_vod__c where RecordType.Name='Prescriber' LIMIT 1 ) ];` but that will return only one record.

Comment: But if `newString` is having five names and there is a account for first name itself,then it will not check for other 4 values in `newString`.

Let me know if I am wrong on this.

Comment: No, you are right, and that what I wrote in my earlier comment. So, I got your requirements clearly now. Let me think over it. :)

Comment: As @Mahmood said,you can use LIMIT clause and as per your question you want to return only one record using SOSL , so that should meet your requirement.If you want something else, please update your question.

Comment: It is no possible with a single query. You can do something with aggregate queries, but you would need to do some additional processing.

Comment: @RahulSharma: Can you let me know what you mean by any example code.